SQL Server Round() incoherence?
I would like to know how exactly the SQL Server round function works.
Others questions say:
PRINT ROUND(1890.125000, 2)
-- produces 1890.130000

PRINT ROUND(1890.124999, 2)
-- produces 1890.12000

all clear, But,
I have a table in SQL that represent sales lines.
The Price column type in SalesPrice table is float and I run this query for one row with a value of 56.705 in the Price field.
SELECT Price, Round(Price, 2) AS RPrice, Round(56.705, 2) AS RDirect
FROM SalesPrice
WHERE Id = nnnnnn;

and the results are:



Price
RPrice
RDirect




56.705
56.7
56.710



I don't understand how this is possible. Any ideas?

It's very likely, and almost assured, that 56.705 is merely the rendering of the floating point number that is stored for this entry. In essence, it's likely that it's already rounded (so to speak) to three decimal digits and that a more precise representation might be something like 5.7049999898899 or something. So you get a rendered 56.705 when selecting the column, but when rounding that float to two decimals, you get 56.70 or 56.7. This just the nature of float and real number storage.

The Price column type in SalesPrice table is float -> why would you use float for prices? Switch to decimal.

You may have some luck casting the float to a decimal before performing the round. See here for an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/OMBnDMor

Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Use something like: cast(Price as decimal(38,35)) and you will see that what you saved  (56.705) in that float column is actually stored as 56.70499999999999829469743417575955391 (representation error in float)

The stored value is not exactly 56.705. This is why float is not a good data type choice for anything to do with money.

Exactly; Money and Decimal are fixed numeric datatypes while Float is an approximate numeric datatype. (and Money * Money is not so great either)
